# Do we have "amplitudes over configurations over spacetime" for QFT in terms of path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, path-integral, probability, correlation-functions

Suppose we work in 1+1 spacetime and consider only a scalar field. In canonical quantization of QFT, a state is a density on "configuration on a time slice" (Let's forget the fact that there is no measure theory on such space). And path integration tells us how propagate from one slice to another. So my question is, in principle, is it possible to define a density on  "configuration on whole spacetime"?

I would expect some thing similar to marginal probability. Given a time slice, the density of a configuration on that time slice is given by integration of those density of configuration on whole spacetime, whose restrictions on the time slice coincides with the given configuration.

And a further question is, we would expect equation of motion would give some restrictions on those densities, so what are they?